# Формирование сложного sql-запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Даны 3 таблицы: 
`article`, 
`article_has_tag` и 
`tag`.

`article` и `tag` имеют связь `M:N` через таблицу `article_has_tag`.

Необходимо написать SQL запрос, достающий первых 20 статей с присоединенным полем `tags` в виде строки включающей все теги, связанные со статьей.

Ребят, кто-то может сформировать запрос? Буду очень благодарен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для конкатенации используйте функцию [group_concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.data) as tags FROM article a
JOIN article_hash_tag aht ON a.id=aht.article_id
JOIN tag t ON aht.tag_id=t.id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id
LIMIT 20
```

Учтите, пожалуйста, что у `GROUP_CONCAT` есть ограничение по размеру. Т.е. если у статьи будет много тэгов, то поле `tags` просто обрежется.
Бороться с этим можно в MySQL: `SET group_concat_max_len=15000;`

Comment: еще есть подозрительная фраза *достающий первых 20 статей*, которая, видимо, потребует order by

Comment: Ну да... добавил в код... :) спасибо

Comment: По-моему запрос cyadvert самый верный.
Это один из вопросов для тестового задания для собеседования.
Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Sasha, не обратил внимание на то, что теги в одной строке нужны, тогда только это решение. Если теги можно объединять где-нить в коде, тогда можно использовать следующий запрос: `SELECT a.*, t.data FROM article a JOIN article_hash_tag aht ON a.id=aht.article_id JOIN tag t ON aht.tag_id=t.id JOIN (SELECT id FROM article ORDER BY id LIMIT 20) article_limit USING(id)` (как-то так, не проверял) Тогда в каждой строке будет одна статья и один связанный с нею тег (всего 20 статей и все теги), затем где-нить в коде эти данные можно будет объединить

Answer (score 0):

В mySQL ответ корректный выше. Для Oracle, c версии 11 и выше:

```html
select ar.id, ar.data, listagg(t.data,',') within group (order by t.id)
  from article ar
  join article_has_tag aht on ar.id = aht.article_id
  join tag t on aht.tag_id = t.id
where rownum < 21
group by ar.id, ar.data 
order by ar.id
```